# Getting count of common words in a sentece using R

Tags: r

My data frame(`usr.bind`) shown below has columns namely query 1 and query 2 . I want to find the count of common words between two queries and add it to "Score"

[image: picture of code]

Here is what I tried but I keep getting same score for all rows and dont know why.

```
usr.bind$Score <- length(intersect(unlist(usr.bind$query1), unlist(usr.bind$query2)))
```

I also tried with

```
usr.bind$Score <- length(intersect(unlist(strsplit((usr.bind$query1)," ")), unlist(strsplit((usr.bind$query2), " "))))
```

but got an error saying `Error in strsplit((usr.bind$query2), " ") : non-character argument`

I also tried using `as.character` but the score for all was same.
Can some one tell me what am I doing wrong.?

PS :Sorry for the data in form of image

I am not sure whether this is right way to add data.. but based on suggestion, here it is for query 1 and 2

Desired Result : count of common words between query 1 and query 2

```
    > dput(head(usr.bind[1:5]))
structure(list(uid1 = structure(c(3L, 25L, 39L, 50L, 59L, 62L
), .Label = c("A0001", "A0005", "A0008", "A0009", "A0010", "A0011", 
"A0015", "A0018", "A0019", "A0020", "A0021", "A0022", "A0024", 
"A0025", "A0026", "A0029", "A0030", "A0033", "A0034", "A0037", 
"A0039", "A0040", "A0041", "A0042", "A0043", "A0044", "A0046", 
"A0047", "A0048", "A0049", "A0050", "A0052", "A0054", "A0056", 
"A0057", "A0059", "A0061", "A0064", "A0065", "A0066", "A0067", 
"A0069", "A0071", "A0073", "A0074", "A0075", "A0077", "A0080", 
"A0081", "A0082", "A0084", "A0087", "A0088", "B0005", "B0007", 
"B0009", "B0012", "B0013", "B0018", "B0020", "B0025", "B0026", 
"B0027"), class = "factor"), uid2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("A0001", "A0005", "A0008", "A0009", "A0010", 
"A0011", "A0015", "A0018", "A0019", "A0020", "A0021", "A0022", 
"A0024", "A0025", "A0026", "A0029", "A0030", "A0033", "A0034", 
"A0037", "A0039", "A0040", "A0041", "A0042", "A0043", "A0044", 
"A0046", "A0047", "A0048", "A0049", "A0050", "A0052", "A0054", 
"A0056", "A0057", "A0059", "A0061", "A0064", "A0065", "A0066", 
"A0067", "A0069", "A0071", "A0073", "A0074", "A0075", "A0077", 
"A0080", "A0081", "A0082", "A0084", "A0087", "A0088", "B0005", 
"B0007", "B0009", "B0012", "B0013", "B0018", "B0020", "B0025", 
"B0026", "B0027"), class = "factor"), query1 = structure(1:6, .Label = c("how to get main method\n new scanner (system.in)\n nextInt()\n do loop\n while-do loop\n what meaning of /n\n nextString\n how to converse case\n how to converse downcase to upcase\n how to converse down case to up case\n how to use euqals to ignoring case\n number format persentage\n use number format to get persentage\n simple\n sample\n JRadioButton\n how to transfer int to color\n how to transfer int to Color\n Color[]\n what method can decide character to operand \n askto method\n ask to method\n", 
"sorting numbers in a array\n", "initialize array list\n", "abstract classes\n subclass\n /n two in a row\n", 
"what is the length method\n how do you know whats private or public\n whats the symbol for private method\n how to create a subclass\n how to create a subclass in java\n how to write a toString\n how to format decimals\n how to use java.text.DecimalFormat\n how to use java.text.DecimalFormat in a string\n", 
"How to call from other class\n How to call methods from other class\n call method from other class\n print method from other class\n call private method from other class\n print private value from other method\n print private value from other class\n parser\n parser java\n array\n read from\n read from java\n read string from java\n parseInteger\n"
), class = "factor"), query2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("how to get main method\n new scanner (system.in)\n nextInt()\n do loop\n while-do loop\n what meaning of /n\n nextString\n how to converse case\n how to converse downcase to upcase\n how to converse down case to up case\n how to use euqals to ignoring case\n number format persentage\n use number format to get persentage\n simple\n sample\n JRadioButton\n how to transfer int to color\n how to transfer int to Color\n Color[]\n what method can decide character to operand \n askto method\n ask to method\n", 
"sorting numbers in a array\n", "initialize array list\n", "abstract classes\n subclass\n /n two in a row\n", 
"what is the length method\n how do you know whats private or public\n whats the symbol for private method\n how to create a subclass\n how to create a subclass in java\n how to write a toString\n how to format decimals\n how to use java.text.DecimalFormat\n how to use java.text.DecimalFormat in a string\n", 
"How to call from other class\n How to call methods from other class\n call method from other class\n print method from other class\n call private method from other class\n print private value from other method\n print private value from other class\n parser\n parser java\n array\n read from\n read from java\n read string from java\n parseInteger\n"
), class = "factor"), Score = c(94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L)), .Names = c("uid1", 
"uid2", "query1", "query2", "Score"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide the data, just a few first rows?

Comment: Added data.. please let me know if there is better way to do it since data is huge

Comment: Desired result is just count of intersecting words between query 1 and 2 strings. data added

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
count_shared_words <- function(s1, s2){
  l1 <- unique(strsplit(s1, split='[\\s::punct::]+')
  l2 <- unique(strsplit(s2, split='[\\s::punct::]+')
  length(intersect(l1, l2))
}
```

Then you could `mapply()` it like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c('the falcon caught the flying squirrels',
         'the sunny days are the worst'),
  b = c('flying with squirrels makes me nervous',
       'days that are sunny make me happy'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$shared_count <- mapply(count_shared_words, s1=df$a, s2=df$b)

df
```

The reason for your `non-character argument error` may be that you are passing other data types into the function -- try converting your strings to true strings (not factors) with `as.character()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, whether I understand your goal well, but consider such a code:

```
countOfSame <- function(s)
{
  merged <- merge(unlist(strsplit(s[1]," ")),unlist(strsplit(s[2]," ")))
  return(sum(apply(merged[!duplicated(merged),],1,function(x) {ifelse(toupper(x[1]) == toupper(x[2]),TRUE,FALSE)})))
}

data <- rbind(c("foo bar","foo jar"),c("foo bar","bar foo"),c("foo foo bar bar","bar"))
cbind(data,apply(data,1,countOfSame))

#result:

     [,1]              [,2]      [,3]
[1,] "foo bar"         "foo jar" "1" 
[2,] "foo bar"         "bar foo" "2" 
[3,] "foo foo bar bar" "bar"     "1"
```

It's not too elegant, but countOfSame takes a vector of two strings and returns number of words (case insensitive) common for both strings. Then you can simply use apply to apply it to two columns of a matrix or a dataframe.